# Two PDO sql statements/Using fetched data for the second statement

Tags: php, sql, variables, pdo

So I'm new to PHP/PDO and I'm having some problems with passing the fetched variable on to the second statement. I'm also having problems with exceptions i don't know how the right structure for this situation.

```
try {   
$connection->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $connection->prepare("CALL sproc_patient_profile_physical_exam_hdr(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindValue(1,$casenumber_fetch,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(2,$patientid_val,PDO::PARAM_INT);  
$stmt->bindValue(3,$enteredby,PDO::PARAM_STR);


while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo $physicalexamid_insert=$row['physicalexamid'];       
    /* I need to use this data for another try and catch or sql statements for example*/

    $count_physical_exam_id = count($physical_exam_id);
    for ($x=0; $x < $count_physical_exam_id; $x++) { 
        if (!(empty($physical_exam_id[$x]))) {
           try {    
            $connection->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $connection->prepare("CALL sproc_patient_profile_physical_exam_dtl(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bindValue(1,$casenumber_fetch,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(2,1,PDO::PARAM_INT);   
            $stmt->bindValue(3,$physical_exam_id[$x],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(4,$physical_exam_desc[$x],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(5,$normal[$x],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(6,$undone[$x],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(7,$specific[$x],PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $stmt->execute();   
            $connection->commit();

            } catch(PDOException $ex) { 
            //$connection->rollBack();
            echo $ex->getMessage();

        }

        }
    }

} 
$stmt->execute();   
$connection->commit();       
} catch(PDOException $ex) { 
$connection->rollBack();
echo $ex->getMessage();
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: whats the problem you are having? can you please mention that ?

Comment: I have two statements/procedure. Its working individually (i've tried it). But I don't know how to execute them both at the same time. I've tried nesting try and catch statements but it doesnt work. Also, I need ' $physicalexamid_insert' on the second stored procedure for my data. Thanks

Comment: You are reusing the same variable `$stmt`, can you use another variable name for the inner `$stmt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with your code:

1. You're not executing the first statement before you call fetch on it.
2. You're over-writing the `$stmt` variable in your loop.

The opening section of your code should be like this:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("CALL sproc_patient_profile_physical_exam_hdr(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindValue(1,$casenumber_fetch,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(2,$patientid_val,PDO::PARAM_INT);  
$stmt->bindValue(3,$enteredby,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Once you've done that you can loop through with a control statement like you're doing (e.g. `while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ... }`).

Inside that control structure, instead of using the variable `$stmt` for a new (second) statement, use something like `$stmt2` or `$inner_stmt`, so that you don't over-write the outer variable.